# getWidth() and getHeight() are 0 after calling setPreferredSize()

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I've been working on my project for a few hours now, only to be constantly frustrated at this.

I have a parent JFrame that adds a JPanel to it, and it is going to be used for the rendering and display of my simulation I'm developing. There are no swing objects that are going to be added to the JPanel, as I will only be using it for rendering shapes using a graphics object.

My code is as such below:

```
public class SimulationPanel extends JPanel {

private BufferedImage junction;
private Graphics2D graphics;

public SimulationPanel() {
    super();
    initPanel();

}

private void initPanel() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600)); //TODO: bug with not sizing the junction correctly.
    junction = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    graphics = junction.createGraphics();
    setBackground(Color.white);


    System.out.println(getWidth());
}
```

The code specifically breaks on the second line of the initPanel() method where I try to create a new BufferedImage.

The output from the exception states "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be > 0"

I'm really unsure on why this is. I've tried to use past answers from Stack Overflow but they were unsuccessful in helping.

This is my first post, so I hope it isn't too bad.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include a sample main? Is the JFrame that the panel is added to visible?

Comment: @LazyCubicleMonkey can't really include a sample main, but this is the class in which the JPanel above is added. This should help provide clarification.
http://pastebin.com/sydYnSgd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the preferred size, you tell the various Java layout managers how you would like your panel to be laid out *once it's added to a container*.  But until it actually is added to the container, it won't have a width or height, and even after it is, it might not have the width and height that you asked for.

One option is to just use 600 directly for the width and height of your new buffered image, and when you add the panel to the JFrame make sure you call `pack()` on the JFrame to allow the window to size to the preferred size of your panel.

Comment: I call pack() after I add all of the components to the necessary parts of the window, but I need to keep a reference to the panel I'm creating (the panel in my OP) in that class as a field. This means I can't just do something in my code like:

contentPane.add(new SimulationPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

Here is my class that uses that panel, and see if you can help me find a solution for this. http://pastebin.com/sydYnSgd

Thanks.

Comment: Is just being "added to a container" enough? I always thought the component has to be realized.

Comment: The actual size of your SimulationPanel is only determined when the container has performed layout. The trigger for this is usually either a call to pack on its parent window or a paint call.

Answer (score 3):

Create your a BufferedImage cache inside your component's paintComponent method. There, you will know the actual size of the component and take that into account for the rendering. The image acts as a cache of your component's content, but you fail to take into account that its size is part of the cached information.

```
@Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  // create cache image if necessary
  if (null == image ||
      image.getWidth() != getWidth() ||
      image.getHeight() != getHeight() ||) {
    image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    imageIsInvalid = true;
  }

  // render to cache if needed
  if (imageIsInvalid()) {
    renderToImage();
  }

  // redraw component from cache
  // TODO take the clip into account
  g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: The cache of the drawing is the intent of what I am trying to do. The drawing reaches the width and height of the panel itself, hence why I want to create the BufferedImage sized to the width and height of the panel.

Comment: @DanielBond Then create your cache image inside `paintComponent`. When the component's size changes, create a new cache image on the next invocation of `paintComponent`. The size of the component is part of your cached state.

Comment: Okay, that clears a bunch of things up. My primary worry of just dumping it all in the paintComponent(...) method was that it would be creating new caches at every instance of the method, but I wasn't thinking about how to prevent that enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Small addition: You might want to skip the rendering in cases that the width or height are 0.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this won't work is that `pack()` is not called (to set all the width and height values) until after the panel has been initiated which is why height and width are not set yet. And BufferedImage will throw an exception if the width or height are non-positive integers.

So why don't you just set the values yourself? Here is how to do it in your example:

```
private void initPanel() {
    final int width = 600;
    final int height = 600;
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    junction = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    graphics = junction.createGraphics();
    setBackground(Color.white);
}
```

**Alternatively:** If you have a requirement where the image has to be resized with the component then you need to. I'm pretty sure when `pack()` is called that it will fire the `ComponentListener.componentResized()` event so this should work when you initiate the component even if you don't resize the component. So instead do this in your code:

```
private void initPanel() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
            Dimension d = c.getSize();
            resizeImage(d);
        }

    });

    this.setBackground(Color.white);
}

public void resizeImage(Dimension d) {
    junction = new BufferedImage(d.getWidth(), d.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    graphics = junction.createGraphics();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good implementation of it. I'll use this.